# Почему не работает загрузка файлов с сервера Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, localhost

Есть локальный сервер:

```js
const 
    express = require('express'),
    server  = express(),
    files   = [
        'Collapse.mp3',
        'Eidolon.mp3'
    ];

server.listen(8080);
server.use(express.static('dist'));

server.get('/', function(request, response) {
    response.send(__dirname + '/dist/index.html');
    response.end();
});

for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    server.get('/dist/downloads/' + files[i], function(request, response) {
        response.download(__dirname + '/dist/downloads/' + files[i]);
    });
}
```

Но не понимаю почему не работает последний цикл для загрузки двух файлов. Выводил при помощи console.log, пути правильные, но при попытке загрузить пишет: 
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'D:\Documents\3-2_web_file_server\dist\downloads\undefined'.

При таком формате все работает:

```js
server.get('/dist/downloads/Collapse.mp3', function(request, response) {
    response.download(__dirname + '/dist/downloads/Collapse.mp3');
});

server.get('/dist/downloads/Eidolon.mp3', function(request, response) {
    response.download(__dirname + '/dist/downloads/Eidolon.mp3');
});
```

Но так не хочется делать так как файлов может быть больше и для каждого не хочется писать отдельный запрос. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема и как это правильнее реализовать. Спасибо.

Comment: Напишите let вместо var

Comment: @AlexeyTen Спасибо, работает!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В чём тут дело: переданная функция вызывается после того как цикл отработал и значение переменной `i` навсегда установилось равным `2`. По такому индексу нет значения в массиве.

```js
var files = ['Collapse.mp3', 'Eidolon.mp3'];
for( var i = 0; i < files.length; ++i ) {
  doSthWithCallbacks(`a-${files[i]}-b`, function() {
     console.log(i, files[i]);
  });
}

function doSthWithCallbacks(str, cb) {
  console.log(`str=${str}`);
  setTimeout(cb, 200);
}
```

Как это обойти - использовать `let` для объявления переменной `i` или:

```js
var files = ['Collapse.mp3', 'Eidolon.mp3'];
files.forEach((file) => {
  doSthWithCallbacks(`a-${file}-b`, function() {
    console.log(file);
  });
});


function doSthWithCallbacks(str, cb) {
  console.log(`str=${str}`);
  setTimeout(cb, 200);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Помогло.